# 'module' object is not callable in python using whois

Tags: python, typeerror

```
import whois 
whois.whois('google.com')
```

Error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Scripts\Email_Header\whois.py", line 1, in <module>     
  import whois   
 File "C:\Scripts\Email_Header\whois.py", line 2, in <module>     
  whois.whois('google.com') 
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I installed using pip install `python-whois`

Answer (score 4):

You've named your script `whois.py` which is masking the `whois` module you *just* downloaded. Python will import the `whois` script you've just wrote, call it and fail.

Name your file differently, for example `scrpt.py` and it works fine:

```
python scrpt.py
{
  "domain_name": [
    "GOOGLE.COM",
    "google.com"
  ],
  "org": "Google Inc.",
  "whois_server": "whois.markmonitor.com",
  "state": "CA",
```

Comment: Isn't there already a duplicate target for these problems?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes and I always *can't* find it because it has a weird name from what I remember.

Comment: Socket Error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
None
 can u please tell me how to check port number on which it was running